# Python putting certain texts into a dictionary from a large string

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to calculate the time duration between tagged On and Off.

Here is an example of two lines from one string:

```
01/01/2015 7:30:10 a.m. Tag off : 16 Address Ave     $1.00   $26.00
01/01/2015 7:40:17 a.m. Tag on : 127 Address St           $27
```

At the moment I am going to ignore the address and focus on calculating time durations. Each line has Tag Off information and Tag On information and I have about 60 lines of them (So 30 pairs) and they all come from one .txt file.

From the above example time duration is 10 minutes and 7 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
def import_file(filename):
    input_file = open(filename, 'r' )
    file_contents = input_file.read()
    input_file.close()

def strip():
    contents = import_file("data.txt")

def duration_cal():
    pass
```

So what is the best way to strip all the unnecessary information and have time and date in relation to On or Off into a dictionary or a list? (To calculate time duration between On and Off)

Comment: *more than 1 space gets reduced down to 1 space.* Put it in code blocks

Comment: How do those timestamps relate to a time difference of 10 minutes and 7 seconds?

Comment: It has been fixed now.

Comment: @user927584 please fix the problem with spaces as well by incorporating Bhargav's comment: just like using the code blocks for actual code, you can use it for snippets of text to preserve all indentation.

Comment: That has also been fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so far it looks you haven't done much research, you only open a file, and you do not even do it the recommended way, as you're creating a function to handle something python has a language structure for.

Then you do not return your file's contents from `import_file()`, so `strip()` will always set `contents` to None. And actually, your functions are not really useful from a design point of view.

A better way to do it, would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, sys

def print_durations(durations):
    # this is to print nicely the durations
    pass

def calculate_durations(contents):
    # this is where the fun shall be, see implementation below
    pass

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: {} filename".format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(1)
    if not os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1]):
        print("Error: {} should be an existing file!".format(sys.argv[1]))
        sys.exit(2)
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        durations = calculate_durations(f.readlines())
        print_durations(durations)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

here's the simplest way to create a script that takes a filename as first argument. If you want a better CLI tool, you might want to try out [`docopt`](http://docopt.org) or [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html).

Now let's get to the fun part, even though you obviously made no efforts to actually *try* to implement the algorithm, which is a reason enough to actually flag your question… But only because it's fun, here's my take at it:

To get the interesting bits of your line, you can pop your python CLI, and split your string to get the relevant parts. If it's consistent across the lines, you don't need to go advanced things like crazy regexps to do so:

```
>>> line = '01/01/2015 7:30:10 a.m. Tag off : 16 Address Ave     $1.00   $26.00'
>>> line.split(' : ')
['01/01/2015 7:30:10 a.m. Tag off','16 Address Ave     $1.00   $26.00']
>>> line.split(' : ')[0]
'01/01/2015 7:30:10 a.m. Tag off'
>>> line.split(' : ')[0].split(' Tag ')
['01/01/2015 7:30:10 a.m.','off']
>>> timestr, status = line.split(' : ')[0].split(' Tag ')
>>> print(status)
off
>>> print(timestr)
01/01/2015 7:30:10 a.m.
```

now you need to convert the time in a fashion that makes it possible to calculate the delta, but as python does not understand `a.m.` as a am/pm marker, you need to convert it first:

```
>>> timestr = timestr.replace('a.m.', 'AM')
>>> import datetime
>>> timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestr, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
>>> timestamp
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 7, 30, 10)
```

finally to get the delta between both timestamps, you just need to substract the dates:

```
>>> timestamp2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(line.split(' : ')[0].split(' Tag ')[0].replace('a.m.', 'AM'), "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
>>> timestamp2 - timestamp
datetime.timedelta(0, 607)
>>> print(timestamp2 - timestamp)
0:10:07
```

and there you go! Here's the same within the function:

```
import datetime

def calculate_durations(contents):
    last_stamp = None
    durations = []
    for line in contents:
        # extract time and status from the line
        timestr, status = line.split(' : ')[0].split(' Tag ')
        # fix a.m./p.m. to be AM/PM
        timestr = timestr.replace('a.m.', 'AM').replace('p.m.', 'PM')
        # load the time as a python timestamp
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestr, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
        # if this is the first timestamp, store the status, and consider the timestamp to be zero
        if last_stamp is None:
            durations.append((datetime.timedelta(0), status))
        # otherwise calculate the timestamp since last
        else:
            durations.append((timestamp-last_stamp, status))
        # save timestamp for next line
        last_stamp = timestamp
    return durations

def print_durations(durations):
    for stamp, status in durations:
        print("{} for {}".format(status, stamp))
```

You can copy that, to test it within a python command line, which will output:

```
>>> contents = [
... '01/01/2015 7:30:10 a.m. Tag off : 16 Address Ave     $1.00   $26.00',
... '01/01/2015 7:40:17 a.m. Tag on : 127 Address St           $27']
...
>>> print_durations(calculate_durations(contents))
off for 0:00:00
on for 0:10:07
```

Or run it as a script, if you put it all together:

```
% python3 myscript.py myfile.log
off for 0:00:00
on for 0:10:07
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the better way of extracting contents from the .txt file is bit confusing as I am still learning how to code.

Comment: I get this error:  `timestr, status = line.split(' : ')[0].split(' Tag ')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` when I run the code with 56 elements in it. It seems like it only works if the length of list is 2

Comment: That means the example data you exposed is not consistent with the data you're parsing. I believe that the issue is that I considered your log to have a single occurrence of ` Tag `. So a possibility would be to change it to ` timestr, status, _ = … ` so it catches all the other parts of the split to put in `_` which is a way to ignore them.

Comment: Now, what's important is not my answer/code, but the methodology I used that helped me do it. You can try splitting, replacing etc your strings within the python REPL, and find out what issues you can get and try to find the rule to parse them all! Finally if the "rule" is too complex, then you might need to use regexps, but try to walk before running ;-)

Comment: Yeah, fortunately I generally get what you did. `timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestr, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")` confuses me because you did `datetime.datetime.strptime` not sure why you did `datetime.datetime`. I'm still getting used to built in functions

Comment: Because the `datetime` module has a `datetime` object that has the strptime classmethod to create datetime objects. You could do `from datetime import datetime` and use `datetime.strptime` to do the same, which is actually more elegant.